# ATL transformation - InterModelReferences. wrong href reference between models

Tags: emf

I have an ATL transformation from 1 model to 2 models

```
-- @nsURI WFG=http://workflowgraph/1.0.3
-- @nsURI SYS=http://systembehavior/1.0
-- @nsURI PEER=http://peerbehavior/1.0

module WFG2System;
create OUT:SYS, OUT2:PEER  from IN:WFG;
```

some objects of the model SYS, have references to objects of the model PEER.
In the ATL run-configuration I have checked the InterModelReferences, and filled in the paths of the files that will be generated. So ATL should know the fileName and path of the produced models. The transformation works, the InterModelReferences works... but not so well. In the 'href' field, instead of the path of the referenced model, there is the String "new-model", like below:

```
<systembehavior:SYS xmlns:PEER="http://peerbehavior/1.0" xmlns:SYS="http://systembehavior/1.0">
  <transitions xsi:type="systembehavior:Send">
    <source href="new-model#Participant_1"/>
    <target href="new-model#Participant_5"/>
  </transitions>
```

instead of be:

```
<systembehavior:SYS xmlns:PEER="http://peerbehavior/1.0" xmlns:SYS="http://systembehavior/1.0">
  <transitions xsi:type="systembehavior:Send">
    <source href="./mymodel.peer#Participant_1"/>
    <target href="./mymodel.peer#Participant_5"/>
  </transitions>
```

Why is not automatically written the path of the second produced model? My actual solution is changing manually with a text editor the href attributes, so that I can open the model file with an XMI editor on eclipse, and then references works well.
thank you

====== EDIT found another problem (solution below)======

If I retrieve the java object SYS from the model, with:

```
ResourceSet resSet = new ResourceSetImpl(); 
        Resource resource = resSet.getResource(URI.createURI(PartesConf.getString("outputPath")+"sys.systembehavior"), true); 
        SystemBehavior sys = ((SystemBehavior) resource.getContents().get(0));
```

the referenced peers from PEER model are empty peers (a peer with all the attributes to null)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The solution of retrieving the referenced objects is using Absolute Paths to retrieve resources. 
For further detail, look at [this discussion](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/1283884/#msg_1283884).
The referenced object will not be always created as java object, but EMF will solve at runtime the reference.

I still have the problem of the wrong href attribute